# Selectively select column data based on date range in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a way in MySQL to select specific columns based on dates entered as variables?

For example, if there is a table containing daily data from Day 1 to Day 31 for various items. Like the table below -

| id | Month | Year | Item | Day 1 | Day 2 | Day3 | Day 4 | Day 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | December | 2021 | Bag | 2 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | December | 2021 | Pencil | 3 | 5 | 1 | 8 | 2 |

This goes up to Day 31 if needed for any number of items in the month.

I'd like to be able to enter a date range such as 2021-12-01 and 2021-12-03 along with the item name 'Bag' and get the sum of the values in that data range - 2+4+2 = 8.

Is this possible?

And if it isn't possible with this current method I'm attempting, is there a way to get it done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the answer you want, but you should seriously fix your data model.  Do not store your dates as columns, but rather store each date's data point in a separate *record*.  So the first record from your sample table would become:

```
id | Item | Date       | num_items
1  | Bag  | 2021-12-01 | 2
1  | Bag  | 2021-12-02 | 4
1  | Bag  | 2021-12-03 | 2
1  | Bag  | 2021-12-04 | 5
1  | Bag  | 2021-12-05 | 1
```

Now your query becomes much more tractable:

```sql
SELECT id, Item, SUM(num_items) AS total
FROM yourTable
WHERE Date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-03' AND Item = 'Bag'
GROUP BY id, Item;
```

Comment: You're right, I will be changing my data model. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please help me with this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70446658/update-3rd-table-based-on-date-range-from-another-table]. It's part of the same problem I'm having trouble with. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

a bit verbose, but you can do something like this :

```
SELECT
   IF (DAY('2021-12-01') <= 1 AND DAY('2021-12-03') >= 1, day1, 0)
 + IF (DAY('2021-12-01') <= 2 AND DAY('2021-12-03') >= 2, day2, 0)
 + IF (DAY('2021-12-01') <= 3 AND DAY('2021-12-03') >= 3, day3, 0)
 + ...
```

Although it's probably better to change your data model to have a date and value as column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll go with your suggestion to change the data model. Thanks.